# Visual Studio Design Time FileNotFoundException on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a solution that uses several projects. Recently, I have centralised all my resources(.resx files) in a diferent dll, called MyLibrary.Resources. So far so good, no compile time errors, neither runtime, but in design time I got this on some of my views:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MyLibrary.Resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=14d55462beec1408' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

The line causing that fail is on a converter(used by the views):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    //Non-relevant converter stuff


    //this line causes the exception
    string translate = MyLibrary.Resources.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(Key); 

    //More non-relevant stuff, with proper return value
}
```

So I can run my app without any problem, but I cannot see some views on the designer.

**Things to have in mind**:

- If I comment the line on the converter, design time works ok, so I am sure that this is the line that fails.
- MyLibrary.Resources does not have any references to other projects, it only contains 2 .resx files storing app strings.
- I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

**Things that I have tried**:

- Check when I am in design mode. I've tried like 6 diferent methods to know if I am in design mode. None of them worked because it looks like design time is ignoring the code. For example, if I add this code to the converter:

  ```
  if (parameter != null)
      string translate = MyLibrary.Resources.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(Key);
  ```

  `parameter` is always null, because I never use it to call the converter. But in design time the exception keeps being thrown, so it looks to me like it is ignoring some code.
- I've tried to debug the design time with another instance of VS, following several SO posts, but I cannot make it work.
- Also I have references to other libraries from my view, doing stuff like painting canvas, so I cannot just stop the "design time creation", because I lose a lot of info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fellow worker of mine has found a solution. I just have to put the crashing reference on a separate function, like that:

```
private System.Resources.ResourceManager GetResourceManager()
{
    return MyLibrary.Resources.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
}
```

And then, I can check if I am in debug mode:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    //Non-relevant converter stuff


    if ((System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "XDesProc")) return value; //use "devenv" instead of "XDesProc" in other versions 
    string translate = GetResourceManager().GetString(Key);

    //More non-relevant stuff, with proper return value
}
```

So, it looks like the designer is checking line by line every code on the converter, even if the code is unreachable, but does not go through functions.